# How to check size of a topic on multi device ROS Communication

Tags: communication, ros-kinetic, message, topic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, experts.

I am trying to ROS communicate with multi device.
There is two PC. First one have a camera sensor, it have publish topics by 30 fps.
Second one have be connected to another by 1Gb Ethernet.
(Exactly, There is a switch-hub for these. it's specs for PCs is enough, 1Gb)

When I subscribe A's image topics, the hz is not 30 hz, **16.8 hz**.

```
$ rostopic bw /my_topic
average: 160.24MB/s
mean: 6.96MB min: 6.96MB max: 6.96MB window: 100
```

The size of a saved image is 476.3 kB.

How can I DEBUG to solve this issue?
How much is size of a ROS topic's header?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302396/how-to-check-size-of-a-topic-on-multi-device-ros-communication/) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2019-01-31**:
The problem is the size of images. So, I implements 10Gb ethernet module on my pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am no expert in this, but if I understand you correctly, that you have a topic with bw 160.24 MB/s and are streaming it over a Gb network, then this is expected behavior. 1Gb is theoretically 125MB, but you will never actually get 125MB/s which would still not be enough to give you 30 fps. In my experience I usually get ~95 MB/s from a Gb network. If you want to test your network google "iperf".

You would need to get the bw of the topics you want to use down. You could do encoding/decoding and/or reduce the fps or resolution of the stream.

I am not sure what you mean by:

```
The size of a saved image is 476.3 kB.
```

How do you get this image, how is it saved? If I would have to guess, I would say the saved image is not the raw feed of the camera. What is the resolution of the video feed?

Also not sure what you mean by ROS topic's header, if you mean the description of the message type, then it is probably in the order of tens of bytes, so probably not the issue here.

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2018-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2018-09-12**:
Thank you.